# Testing package depending on other package

Tags: python, unit-testing

Earlier I haven't cared much about writing tests, but now I want to have a look at it. But I directly run into problems. There are many tutorials about how to writes tests, but I haven't found anything about how to when a package requires another (not built-in) package to work.

I have two packages; let's call them `foo` and `bar`. The package `bar` requires  `foo` to work. Now I want to write a test for `bar`.

What is the best/recommended solution to make sure that `foo` is installed somewhere so that `bar` can find `foo` when the tests are run? Is it to just manually install `foo` before testing `bar`?

Note: Neither of the packages is published to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

Comment: Please give an example of what you tried out. The question is very general.

Comment: @MUNGAINJOROGE. I haven't tried anything out because I wanted to learn the recommended way to do it. And my question is general because it is a generic problem. Showing the code of my packages would make the question clearer.

Comment: Then, whether the packages are in PyPi or Not, give ``bar`` the responsibility of finding ``foo``. Which means that when writing tests you are actually testing bar and you don't have to care about its dependencies. You might want to have a look at python packages/modules https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/

Comment: @MUNGAINJOROGE. How would you solve it so that `bar` finds `foo`?

Comment: Assuming you are on Linux, create a directory in $HOME/python_private_modules, then append this to $PYTHONPATH in .bashrc as ``export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/python_private_modules``. Add ``foo`` into this directory and now in any python project you will be able to do ``import foo``.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my guess is that your problem is that `foo` cannot be found when you're running your tests for `bar` (e.g. a `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`). If that's the case, then your problem is likely due to your project's file/dir organization (see this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490860/relative-imports-with-unittest-in-python) for a solution).

Alternatively, perhaps your problem is that you don't have the `foo` package located within `bar` as a submodule. Or maybe you don't have `foo` pip installed globally. If this is the case, then you need to set up a virtual environment (the built-in [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) library is one way) where `foo` is pip installed. You mentioned that `foo` isn't on PyPi, but if you've got it on GitHub you can easily add it to a `requirements.txt` to have it pulled and installed within your virtual environment.

If those solutions don't answer your question, then maybe you're in fact asking about how you can control the behavior of `foo` when `bar` is under test? If so, then you should look into **mocking** and/or **patching**, which are ways you can create an 'fake' object within your test suite to imitate and substitute for another object within your program. In your case, you want to patch `foo` so that your test(s) for `bar` don't depend on how `foo` behaves. Isolating `bar` like this is integral to the concept of unit testing.

Assuming you're using `unittest`, there's the excellent `unittest.mock` module. `unittest.mock` provides a class called `Mock` that you can use to imitate real objects in your codebase. The library also provides a function called `patch()` that replaces the real objects in your code with `Mock` instances. You can use `patch()` as either a decorator or a context manager, giving you control over the scope in which the object will be mocked. Once the designated scope exits, `patch()` will clean up your code by replacing the mocked objects with their original counterparts. I've found [this article](https://realpython.com/python-mock-library/#what-is-mocking) to be handy when getting started with `Mock` and `patch()`.

Hopefully I somehow answered your question. If not, let me know and I can update!

Comment: Making `foo` a submodule of `bar` doesn't sound like a good solution. What if I would have several unrelated packages, all depending on `foo`? I cannot make `foo` a submodule of all of the. That would also make it a bit difficult to install `foo` without having to also install `bar`.

Comment: Mocking also doesn't sound correct in this case. The library `foo` implements points and vectors, among other geometric things. The library `bar` uses points and vectors. Had `foo` implemented some kind of service then dependency injection and mocking could have been a proper solution, but I don't think that it is in this case.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. It is correct that my problem is that `foo` cannot be found when I'm running my tests for `bar`. The question is what is the best way to make sure it is.