# python unittest relative import

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-unittest

This question is related to [Relative imports with unittest in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490860/relative-imports-with-unittest-in-python) but I would like to specifically ask about the importance of how unittest handles/modifies imports.

Say I have a package structure:

```
containing_folder/
    project/
        main_program.py
        random_module_a/
            a.py
            a_test.py
```

`a_test.py` contains a relative import of `a.py` like:

```
import a
```

To run my unit tests I go to the outer folder and run unittest:

```
cd project
python -m unittest random_module_a/a_test.py
```

This does not work and I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

However, if I modify the import as follows the test runs fine:

```
# in `test_a.py`
from random_module_a import a
```

Why does the relative import (the first version) not work with unittest? I am confused because if I wanted to run `a_test` as a script then it can import `a` just fine without the `from random_module_a` bit.

Answer (score 0):

To import `a.py` from the current directory, use:

```
from . import a
```

Note that you must do this inside a package.